How can I make sure my oil do not contain salt
Vacuuming slightly wet wood with my vacuum pump resulted in making a mayonnaise with my pump oil - which turned out surprisingly stable. I mixed salt saturated water with it in order to break the emulsion (by raising the density of the water) and after days, my oil looks clear again...
However, I'm now a bit frightened : What if some salt remained in suspension in the oil. Wouldn't it corrode my pump ? How could I make sure my oil is clean enough ?

Yes, the salt would corrode your pump. It is hygroscopic. Maybe consider an oil change all together.

What you can try is doing several repeats of gravity passing oil via funnel with filtration paper (any water soaking paper would do), making very tiny hole at the tip for the oil able to slowly drop. But oil exchange is the sure bet.

Yes, I know that oil change would be the best thing, but the point is that it is something that might happen again and it could end up being quite expensive if I need to completely replace the oil every time.

@Camion Based on your description, I presume you joined the oil pump directly to the container of your sample.  A frequently used element on small lab scale, for instance with Schlenk lines is a cold trap with liquid nitrogen, or (less cold:) dry ice with isopropanol.  Liquids which otherwise would condense on the high-pressure side of the oil pump are then retained as a solid by these traps.  Often made of glass, there are larger ones of stainless steel, too.

See https://www.thomassci.com/nav/cat1/traps/cat2/traps_vaportraps/0 and https://www.westlab.com.au/moisture-trap-drain-valve-for-663-833-vacuum-pump for some examples of moisture and vapor traps. Sorry, but I would discard the used vacuum oil, lest it destroy the pump... but then use a vapor trap to prevent a repetition.

1/ What if checked the oil by simply putting a piece of nude iron, in order to see if it was corroded ? 2/ about the idea of using a vapor trap, One of my project with this pump was to try myself at food lyophilisation. Wouldn't it defeat the purpose of the vapor trap since the pressure needs to be low enough to take vapor away from deep frozen food.

@Camion 1) the corrosion equally requires some water; but perhaps the mayonnaise like appearance of the oil isn't only because of water trapped, but equally by air (e.g., via the gas ballast). 2) Set and lock scale B to 100C about the boiling point of water at atmospheric pressure here, move C to 15mmHg, read scale A -- about freezing.

@Camion For a good oil pump, 15mmHg as remaining pressure is not much work.  With lower pressures, it even can be useful to warm the samples to accelerate the removal of water.  It could be question how much volume of gas per unit of time the pump is able to transport.  It is not rare to have some "snow" like deposit in a cold trap attached to a Schlenk line and oil pump at low pressure which becomes a liquid as soon as the one stops the operation to dismount and clean the trap (back at atmospheric pressure).
